# Conditional with categories

Tags: categories, conditionals

So I'm trying to conditionally display an embed within an entry based on several parameters: channel_short_name and category. So I have a conditional that checks a few items and then if it matches has an embed that passes along with it the categories that are in the entry.

Below is the template code I initially wrote. There are a couple of issues.
1. It has nested {categories} tags and EE doesn't like that and throws an error.
2. If I just remove the embeds for now (so that something at least renders), I can end up with multiple instances of the embed since the top {categories} tag is a loop and entries can have more than one category assigned.

So is there maybe a way I can just assign all the categories to a variable and use that instead of wrapping the whole thing in a {categories} tag?

```
{categories}
    {if channel_short_name=="webcast-partner" OR channel_short_name=="webcast-mssp" OR category_id==93}
        {embed="_includes/.resource-carousel1" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
    {if:elseif channel_short_name=="webcast-customer"}
        {embed="_includes/.resource-carousel2" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
    {if:elseif category_id==60}
        {embed="_includes/.resource-carousel3" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
    {if:else}
        {embed="_includes/.resource-carousel4" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
    {/if}
{/categories}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured it out:

```
{if channel_short_name=="webcast-partner" OR channel_short_name=="webcast-mssp" OR "|{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}"*="|93|"}
    {embed="_includes-v2/.resource-carousel1" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
{if:elseif channel_short_name=="webcast-customer"}
    {embed="_includes-v2/.resource-carousel2" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
{if:elseif "|{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}"*="60"}
    {embed="_includes-v2/.resource-carousel3" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
{if:else}
    {embed="_includes/.resource-carousel4" cat="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
{/if}
```